# Produce a single file .mobi using Calibre

Tags: calibre, mobi

I'm trying to convert an epub to mobi using Calibre, and I would like to produce the ebook as a single file. I've tried selecting the "insert metadata as page at start of book" as some guides suggest, however this is not enough to display the cover image.

If I save to disk and copy the whole folder to my kindle device, it displays the cover image correctly. However it doesn't if I copy only the .mobi file.

Any suggestion or workaround?

Comment: I think the appropriate way is to right click on the book in question and select "send specific format to device" or something similar and then it will copy the book appropriately to the kindle.  You will probably see a similar folder structure to what you copied.